# Batch files to copy the single file created with a Time Stamp in the title

Tags: datetime, batch-file, cmd, copy, filenames

I am writing batches, let's call them Batch A and Batch B.  Batch A runs multiple inventory checks of the local source area and the cloud destination area.  Then it moves the files to the cloud and re-runs the inventory checks (dir, aws s3 ls).  The inventory checks are important for my logging found in Batch B.

Batch B looks like this;

```
@echo off
SET HMSH=%TIME::=%
SET HMSH=%HMSH:.=%

SET MM=%DATE:~4,2%
SET DD=%DATE:~7,2%
SET YYYY=%DATE:~10,4%

SET YMD=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%
SET STAMP=%YMD%%HMSH%
Echo TIME "STAMP" SET TO TITLE THE LOG FILE
@ECHO ON
c:\Users\User\Desktop\BatchA.bat >c:\Users\User\Desktop\AWS\Log_Testing\%STAMP%_NIGHTLYS3.log

COPY c:\Users\User\Desktop\AWS\Log_Testing\%STAMP%_NIGHTLYS3.log J:\AWSNIGHTLYS3LOGS\
```

Where I set STAMP, then run BATCHA.bat with a log generating in Log_Testing which uses %STAMP% in the field name.

My logic and task flow seems correct in that the COPY command should look for the exact file (and that file only, to avoid copy and rewriting hundreds of files over and over) based on the STAMP function which was generated in this batch running time (should be unchanged as it is SET as when it was first set).

The only way I can test this file (which works 100% up to the Copy command) is to run it and looks for the copied file in the last line's destination.

It fails, any ideas out there?

thank you all and sorry in advance, I've been learning this for the last month on and off at an IT company. I was a marketing major haha not sure how I wound up here.

Comment: What does "it fails" mean?  Maybe just turn ECHO ON for the whole batchb and give the complete output here?

Comment: I don't believe `%stamp%` is, what it should be. Please do a `echo -%stamp%-` before `@ECHO ON`. What's the output?

Comment: @Bubbafat by fails I mean that upon checking the copy destination folder there is nothing there.

Comment: `C:\Users\User>@echo off
SET HMSH=%TIME::=%
SET HMSH=%HMSH:.=%

SET MM=%DATE:~4,2%
SET DD=%DATE:~7,2%
SET YYYY=%DATE:~10,4%

SET YMD=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%
SET STAMP=%YMD%%HMSH%
@echo on

C:\Users\User>echo -%stamp%
-2014011016433950`

This is the output I want in my file names so that I can have inverted chronological sorting of my logs.  Also the coders and managers here would like the file names to lead off with this.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. Now we need someone to run our computer system. Who's best? Oh! a marketeer of course!

Your problem is that invoking a batch file transfer control to that batch file, so `c:\Users\User\Desktop\BatchA.bat ...` never returns.

You need

```
call c:\Users\User\Desktop\BatchA.bat....
```

Answer (score 0):

This debugging code will help you narrow down the fault:

Maybe there is a space where there shouldn't be one.

```
SET STAMP=%YMD%%HMSH%
echo "%stamp%"
pause
Echo TIME "STAMP" SET TO TITLE THE LOG FILE
@ECHO ON
c:\Users\User\Desktop\BatchA.bat >c:\Users\User\Desktop\AWS\Log_Testing\%STAMP%_NIGHTLYS3.log
if not exist "c:\Users\User\Desktop\AWS\Log_Testing\%STAMP%_NIGHTLYS3.log" (
echo look for a file called "c:\Users\User\Desktop\AWS\Log_Testing\%STAMP%_NIGHTLYS3.log" 
pause
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, I have found a solution.
the issue was that the machine would get to the next line (the COPY) and begin running that while the last line was finalizing the log file.

I loaded a couple DIR statements to pause before the last line (avoiding loading new commands onto each CMD).

That fixed the final stages of this operation and the file now is copied to the correct location.

Thank you all again for the help and helping me look at things from a different angle.

-Jon